# How to do CF push for a Gradle project spring boot.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, cloud-foundry

How to do CF push for a Gradle project spring boot.?

What files are needed to be added to project and in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any additional files or configuration for Gradle. Use Gradle to build a `.jar` or `.war` file as usual, then push the archive to CF with a command like

```
$ cf push example-app -p build/libs/example-app.jar
```

You can add a [`manifest.yml`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html) file to the project to store some of the optional settings for the application.

There is an example of building and pushing a Gradle-built application here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music#running-the-application-on-cloud-foundry

Comment: Yup, thanks it worked. Just a question out of curiosity, I wanted to use the values from manifest.yml inside my application. May be something like manifest to application.property file

Comment: Which values? Most can be found in various environment variables accessible by your app when it's running. Bound services will show up in the `VCAP_SERVICES`, application metadata is under `VCAP_APPLICATION` and there are some others like `MEMORY_LIMIT` and a handful prefixed with `CF_`. If you have actuator installed, look at the endpoint to dump env variables and you can see what's available.